# Graph within graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to combine a time series and a histogram to appear together like the example below:
[image: Combined graphs]

I just want one to be scaled without distortion and placed freely within the second but I haven't found yet a code snipped for this.

The graph was taken from [here](http://neuroscience.telenczuk.pl/?p=331), but it involves merging 2 svg graphs. Can this be done directly in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the `axes()` function, as shown in [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html) from the matplotlib gallery. My favourite way to see if something is possible with matplotlib is to scan through the gallery for something that looks similar to what I want.

Unfortunately, matplotlib's site appears to have just gone down. There's an older copy [on Github](http://matplotlib.github.com/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html).